# Iterating over keys and values of a dictionary in mustache / pystache

Tags: python, mustache, pystache

Suppose I have simple dictionary like this:

```
d = {'k1':'v1', 'key2':'val2'}
```

How can I render `key, value` lines in pystache using that dictionary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to transform your dictionary a bit. Using the mustache syntax, you can only iterate through lists of dictionaries, so your dictionary `d` has to become a list where each key-value pair in `d` is a dictionary with the key and value as two separate items, something like this:

```
>>> [{"k": k, "v": v} for k,v in d.items()]
[{'k': 'key2', 'v': 'val2'}, {'k': 'k1', 'v': 'v1'}]
```

Complete sample program:

```
import pystache

tpl = """\
{{#x}}
 - {{k}}: {{v}}
{{/x}}"""

d = {'k1':'v1', 'key2':'val2'}

d2 = [{"k": k, "v": v} for k,v in d.items()]
pystache.render(tpl, {"x": d2})
```

Output:

```
 - key2: val2
 - k1: v1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use tuples, a bit less verbose:

```
import chevron

tpl = """\
{{#x}}
 - {{0}}: {{1}}
{{/x}}"""

d = {'k1':'v1', 'key2':'val2'}

d2 = [(k, v) for k,v in d.items()]
print(chevron.render(tpl, {"x": d2}))
```